# Jersey2 @BeanParam being significantly slower than the alternative

Tags: java, performance, http, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Working on a project were I migrated some methods from inline `@QueryParam` param lists into `@BeanParam` I noticed a significant and unexplained impact in latency.
I am unsure what internals are causing this issue because it does not seem to be just the new Bean creation, since an empty Bean is as fast as no Bean.  Also `@QueryParam`s added into the Bean increase the latency proportionally, the same definitely does not happen at the method level.

The difference between both forms is huge in terms of latency, the `@BeanParam` one takes 20% longer despite doing essentially the same.

```java
@Path("test1")
public Response test1(@QueryParam("instring") String one, @QueryParam("instring2") String two)
```

vs

```java
public class Params {
   @QueryParam("instring") String one;
   @QueryParam("instring2") String two;
}
@Path("test2")
public Response test2(@BeanParam Params params)
```

I have created a minimal example [here](https://gist.github.com/arkaitzj/cd07ee44873fe9c1a73883888c37da65).

My goal is to find a workaround for this since I really find `@BeanParam` very nice to organise groups of params and its not clear to me where the latency increase comes from, perhaps there is some kind of hint I can supply to eliminate the perf hit.

Comment: But reflection is used to set the bean values on the bean. There is not this extra step with the parameters. In case one, the parameters are retrieved from the map, then the resource method is called. In the second case, the parameters are retrieved, then the bean needs to get created, have its values set with reflection, then the resource method is called.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha but the latency increase is huge, in my example the handler bodies sleep for 1ms and having 5 parameters increases that by 20% which is disproportionated. Also the object creation is negligible when we have one or no queryparam. From where I sit it looks as if the problem is actual bean field injection, I am not sure if I could speed that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @paul-samsotha mentioned, the additional latency you are encountering seems to be associated with the reflection used to associate query params with the bean fields after the bean is constructed.

Taking your example, commenting out all the `Params` bean fields initially and running the tests multiple times, adding a field back into the `Params` bean on each run you get the following results:

**No Fields: Commenting all fields out of Params class**

```
15:14:53.664 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warming up
15:15:35.562 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warmed up
15:15:49.244 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs1: 731.101 10000 in 13.68
15:16:02.968 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs2: 728.7037 10000 in 13.72
15:16:17.016 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Req2/Req1 1.0032899
```

**Single Field: First param only**

```
15:16:57.160 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warming up
15:17:26.052 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warmed up
15:17:39.715 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs1: 732.06445 10000 in 13.66
15:17:54.582 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs2: 672.6759 10000 in 14.87
```

**...**

**3 Fields: First 3 string params**

```
15:20:33.870 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warming up
15:21:01.859 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warmed up
15:21:15.825 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs1: 716.17847 10000 in 13.96
15:21:30.926 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs2: 662.2078 10000 in 15.10
```

**...**

**All params**

```
15:23:55.339 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warming up
15:24:25.717 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warmed up
15:24:39.376 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs1: 732.2789 10000 in 13.66
15:24:55.676 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs2: 613.5346 10000 in 16.30
15:24:55.676 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Req2/Req1 1.1935413
```

The performance gradually gets worse as more Bean fields are added.

As a workaround you could update your Bean class as follows:

```
@ToString
public static class Params {
    String instring;
    String inint;
    int inint2;
    int inint3;
    String inint4;
    String inint5;
    String inint6;
    String inint7;

    Params(@Context UriInfo allUri){
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = allUri.getQueryParameters();
        instring = params.getFirst("instring");
        inint = params.getFirst("inint");
        inint2 = toInt(params.getFirst("inint2"));
        inint3 = toInt(params.getFirst("inint3"));
        inint4 = params.getFirst("inint4");
        inint5 = params.getFirst("inint5");
        inint6 = params.getFirst("inint6");
        inint7 = params.getFirst("inint7");
    }

    int toInt(String value){
        return nonNull(value) ? Integer.parseInt(value) : -1;
    }
}
```

This update should eliminate the reflection mapping stage and result in improved performance:

```
15:35:16.713 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warming up
15:35:45.513 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Warmed up
15:35:59.493 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs1: 715.5123 10000 in 13.98
15:36:13.536 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Reqs2: 712.0986 10000 in 14.04
15:36:13.536 [main] INFO  org.example.ProofOfConcept - Req2/Req1 1.004794
```

Comment: Hi, yes as mentioned in the question, it gets proportionally worse as we add parameters so it is clearly that.  However, if you create a constructor with all the @QueryParams in there it is still proportionally slower which seems to indicate it is not the actual bean field injection.
I don't want to lose the annotation based tests and checks and I was hoping for a solution that makes reflection faster, visibility tricks or something.